# TreeView doesn't refresh after changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, treeview

I write a program for edition of IIS web.config file. I have a problem with my TreeView control which doesn't want to refresh itself after I change something in the source XmlDocument variable.
It's the WPF project.

Window resources in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" />
</Window.Resources>
```

My TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="XmlTree" Grid.Row="1"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=*}"
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"
   SelectedItemChanged="XmlTree_SelectedItemChanged" />
```

TreeView style:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AttributeTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            Margin="3,0,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmAttributeBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="=&quot;"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlValueBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <TextBlock Text="&quot;"
             Foreground="{StaticResource xmlMarkBrush}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="False">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="?" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
        <ItemsControl
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AttributeTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Attributes}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <Binding XPath="*" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Text">
            <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
            <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
private XmlDocument _xml;
private XmlElement _selectedElement; // actually selected item in TreeView
private XmlDataProvider _xmlDataProvider;
private string _tempFileName = @"C:\test.xml";

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    XmlTree.Style = (Style)FindResource("TreeViewAllExpandedStyle");
    _xmlDataProvider = FindResource("XmlData") as XmlDataProvider;
}

private void OpenXmlFile(string filePath)
{
    XmlEditor.Clear(); // my text editor provided by AvalonEdit
    XmlEditor.Load(filePath);

    _xml = new XmlDocument();
    _xml.Load(filePath);

    if(_xmlDataProvider.Document == null)
        _xmlDataProvider.Document = _xml;
}

private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some changes on _selectedElement (changes applies also into _xml)

    _xml.Save(_tempFileName);
    RefreshViews();
}

private void RefreshViews()
{
    // 
    OpenXmlFile(_tempFileName);

    // here I want to refresh my TreeView
    // I noticed that when I select back my changed item, its values are set, but in my tree I see the old ones...
    // I tried to do XmlTree.Focus() (nothing happens excepting control focus)
    // and _xmlDataProvider.Refresh() (here comes NullReferenceException)
    // I guess something bad happens in OpenXmlFile(...) method, because I reopen _xml and _xmlDataProvider looses a handler to it?
}
```

Could anyone explain why it doesn't work?

**[edit]**

I tried to modify 2 methods like this:

```
private void OpenXmlFile(string filePath)
{
    XmlEditor.Clear();
    XmlEditor.Load(filePath);

    _xml = new XmlDocument();
    _xml.Load(filePath);

    _xmlDataProvider.Document = _xml;
}

private void saveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    _xmlDataProvider.Document.Save(_tempFileName);
    _xmlDataProvider.Refresh();
}
```

And now I get NullReferenceException while `_xmlDataProvider.Refresh();`

Comment: Calling `_xmlDataProvider.Refresh();` will not refresh your file if you are loading it from one path, but saving changes to `_tempFileName`.  You probably want `saveChangesButton_Click()` to still call `OpenXmlFile()`.  In addition, setting `_xmlDataProvider.Document` automatically calls `_xmlDataProvider.Refresh()` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.document.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can try with Binding Two-Way on your TreeView and observable collection.

```
{Binding .... Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Firslty you can modify your binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=*, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: I regret but it doesn't work for me. I've even tried to modify my code behind to fit it more to your propose, but it hasn't been working:/

Comment: for me that's work on my project that's sure Mode Two Way is made for this situaion, in order to have binding from source on control or from control on source, it's good practise

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the value of `xmlDataProvider.Document` in your `OpenXmlFile()` function if it is null.  When you set 
`_xml = new XmlDocument();`, it sets `_xml` to point to a new object, but `xmlDataProvider` is still pointing to the old object.  Then, you have the following two lines:

```
if(_xmlDataProvider.Document == null)
    _xmlDataProvider.Document = _xml;
```

If you're getting in here from `RefreshViews()`, `_xmlDataProvider.Document` will not be null, so you're never refreshing the XML file tied to your data provider.

Comment: Could you describe how to change it? How to tie a new instance of _xml to the data provider?

Comment: I would recommeng getting rid of the null-check, or going with the two-way binding suggestion by Aghilas.

Comment: Your code is no longer calling `RefreshViews()`.  Calling `_xmlDataProvider.Refresh();` won't work because you're saving your changes to a different file and refershing the data provider will reload the file you first specified.